# How do I add Foreign Key to the Table as a column

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have two tables as below:

Table name: table_1

| ID | studentId | Date | enrolled | parent name | parents annual income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | 2022/01/13 14:39:15 | enrolled | ABC | 12345 |
| 2 | 12345 | 2022/01/13 14:39:06 | not-enrolled | ABC | 10345 |
| 3 | 12345 | 2022/01/13 8:03:44 | not-enrolled | ABC | 1467 |

I am working on refactoring this table as it has some flaws and redundant data. Also, the date is mentioned in this table as VARCAR(20).

I want to refactor it into 2 tables as below:

**Table A** --Only 1 entry for each student ID, the first date when entry was made in the table, the latest enrolled status of the student, and parent name (made the entries in the table_1 bold)

Table name: table_2

| ID | studentId | strat_date | enrolled | parent name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | 2022/01/13 8:03:44 | enrolled | ABC |

**Table B** -- The rest of the history data

Table name: table_3

| ID | studentId_1 | Date | parents annual income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022/01/13 14:39:15 | 12345 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022/01/13 14:39:06 | 10345 |
| 3 | 1 | 2022/01/13 8:03:44 | 1467 |

The "ID" column in the "table_2" table is the PRIMARY KEY.
The "studentId_1 " column in the "table_3" table is a FOREIGN KEY.

I know how to create table_2.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_2 (studentId, `start_date`, `status`, `parent name`)
SELECT studentId, MIN(`Date`), MIN(enrolled), `parent name`
FROM table_1
GROUP BY studentId, `parent name`;
SELECT * FROM table_2;
```

Which gives an output:

| ID | studentId | strat_date | enrolled | parent name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | 2022/01/13 8:03:44 | enrolled | ABC |

How do I create table_3 as it has "FOREIGN KEY" in the table as below:

| ID | studentId_1 | Date | parents annual income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022/01/13 14:39:15 | 12345 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022/01/13 14:39:06 | 10345 |
| 3 | 1 | 2022/01/13 8:03:44 | 1467 |

Comment: `Date` and `enrolled` in `table_2` are obviously excess. These values can be easily retrieved from `table_3`.

Comment: @Akina Yes, it is redundant. I made this with duplicate data.   With real data, it makes sense to have these fields in table_2. We can discard enrolled column from table_3

Comment: Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=283b41c073d567e06abb846a3dfc5473 Adjust to your needs, add/move/remove columns if needed. PS. You may use natural PK in `table_2` (the column `studentId`) and remove synthetic PK.

Comment: @Akina I also would like to have the first date a student record appeared in the table and latest status. I would like to know how to filter those two columns in particular

Comment: Use not DISTINCT but GROUP BY and MIN() for the date column. For last status - use correlated subquery in output list, for example, or according CTE with FIRST_VALUE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 (
    ID INT,
    studentId INT,
    `Date` DATETIME,
    enrolled VARCHAR(255),
    `parent name` VARCHAR(255),
    `parents annual income` INT
);
INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES
(1, 12345,  '2022/01/13 14:39:15',  'enrolled', 'ABC',  12345),
(2, 12345,  '2022/01/13 14:39:06',  'not-enrolled', 'ABC',  10345),
(3, 12345,  '2022/01/13 8:03:44',   'not-enrolled', 'ABC',  1467),
(4, 67890,  '2022/01/12 14:39:15',  'enrolled', 'DEF',  12345),
(5, 67890,  '2022/01/14 14:39:06',  'not-enrolled', 'DEF',  10345),
(6, 67890,  '2022/01/14 8:03:44',   'not-enrolled', 'DEF',  1467);
SELECT * FROM table_1;
```

```
CREATE TABLE table_2 (
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    studentId INT,
    `start_date` DATETIME,
    `status` VARCHAR(255),
    `parent name` VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    UNIQUE (studentId)
);
CREATE TABLE table_3 (
    ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    studentId_Id INT,
    `Date` DATETIME,
    enrolled VARCHAR(255),
    `parents annual income` INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_studentId_Id  FOREIGN KEY (studentId_Id) REFERENCES table_2 (ID) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

To Insert the data into table_2 from table_1:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_2 (studentId, `start_date`, `status`, `parent name`)
SELECT studentId, MIN(`Date`), MIN(enrolled), `parent name` 
FROM table_1
GROUP BY studentId, `parent name`;
SELECT * FROM table_2;
```

To Insert the data into table_3 from table_1 in relation with table_2:

```
INSERT INTO table_3 ( studentId_Id, `Date`, enrolled, `parents annual income`)
SELECT t1.ID, t2.`Date`, t2.enrolled, t2.`parents annual income` 
FROM table_2 AS t1, table_1 as t2
WHERE t1.studentId = t2.studentId;
SELECT * FROM table_3;
```